# How to prove r → (∃ x : α, r) in Lean

Tags: logic, proof, theorem-proving, lean

I'm trying to prove the logical statement `r → (∃ x : α, r)`, where `r` is a `Prop` (a proposition or statement) and `α` is a `Type`. I've proved a few things in Lean, going through the exercises of the book, but I'm stuck on this one.

I'm really not sure I even understand why this is true. Wouldn't `α` being uninhabited make this a false statement since no `x` of type `α` exists?

My best "attempts" were 1) hoping that lean's elaborator would fill in what I needed,

```
theorem t5_2: r → (∃ x : α, r) :=
  assume rx: r,
    ⟨_, rx⟩
```

but it can't deduce something of type `α`, which makes sense. And 2) I also thought that this might be a non-constructive proof, so I was thinking of doing a proof by contradiction. However, the furthest I got on paper was

```
  ¬ (∃ x : α, r) → (∀ x : α, ¬ r) → ??
```

I'm not sure how to perform that first implication in lean, and even if I did, I would still need an `x` of type `α` to eliminate the `∀`.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question would be better in the Mathematics forum.

Comment: I asked it there as well, but stack overflow has a lean tag and the Mathematics forum does not. If you want to vote to close you can. I've seen a few lean questions here but none on the Mathematics forum.

Comment: @EnricoBorba You are correct in that this is not provable for all α. Where did you get the exercise from?

Comment: I got it [here](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/quantifiers_and_equality.html#the-existential-quantifier). It's at the bottom of section 4.4, the second of many `example` problems with `sorry` at the end.

Comment: Your comment about the type being inhabited is correct. However note that TPiL says "Notice that the declaration `variable a : α` amounts to the assumption that there is at least one element of type α. This assumption is needed in the second example, as well as in the last two." after the exercise you are asking about.

Comment: @banbh Ahhhhhhh. Sweet release. Thank you, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement isn't true in general. `α` could be `empty`:

```
example : ¬ ∀ (α : Type) (r : Prop), r → (∃ x : α, r) :=
begin
  intro h,
  cases h empty _ true.intro with w,
  cases w
end
```

You can prove the original statement if you assume `[inhabited α]`

```
example (α : Type) [inhabited α] (r : Prop) : r → (∃ x : α, r) :=
λ h, ⟨inhabited.default α, h⟩
```